# Java inherited class functions variable names

Tags: java, android-studio, interface

I'm writing an SDK for android,

I have an interfce that the sdk users are supposed to implement, 
when the class is implemented the variable names are set to var1, var 2:

my interface:

```
 public interface MyDevice {

    void onNewDevice(String address, int group);

  }
```

when implementing (added with "add unimplemented methods"):

```
MyDevice d = new MyDevice(){

        @Override
        public void onNewDevice(String s, int i) {

        }
};
```

Can I have any control over this?? Is there a way to add comments to my interface that will appear in the implementing class?

many thanks!!

Comment: What exactly do you mean?

Comment: have you tried generating javadoc on the interface?

Comment: You want control over the parameter names generated by the IDE?

Comment: You should interact with people who answer you question: If they're helpful upvote, if they fixed your problem accept, and if you need a little more help and clarification comment on the answer.

Answer (score 0):

technically yes.  You would do this in the interface:

```
/**
*    Some documentation
*/
void onNewDevice(String address, int group);
```

When you generate the javadoc the function in the implementing class will reference the parent classes documentation.  If you instead are asking how to document the function explicitly in an automatic fashion, that is a bit of a different problem to solve.  In general though, it would not make sense to duplicate the documentation for the sake of documentation.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the javadoc indicators, the javadoc will be available to implementors that hover over the method name in e.g. Android Studio / Eclipse

```
/**
 * My Javadoc explains my interface
 */
public interface MyDevice {

    /**
     * My Javadoc explains my method
     * @param address some explanation
     * @param group some explanation
     */
    void onNewDevice(String address, int group);

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Java doesn't allow variables to be defined in interfaces, so there is no way to *force* implementing classes to have certain variables or certain variable names. Would you be able to use an abstract class instead? An abstract class could not only create the variables, but also define a constructor that assigns the parameters to them.